# How to find all the ranges in an array of numbers

Tags: arrays, ruby, range

I have an array of numbers that sorted. I need a method that return ranges of numbers in this array.

```
input: [1,2,3,7,9,10,11,13]
output: [(1..3),(7..7),(9..11),(13..13)]
```

Comment: A small thing, but it's helpful to express each input as a Ruby object to which a variable is assigned (e.g., `arr = [1,2,3,7,9,10,11,13]`). That way readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them, all readers refer to the same variables (here just `arr`) and cutting-and-pasting is facilitated. Your statement of the desired output is fine, but you may wish to write `"desired output: ..."` or `"expected output: ..."`.

Comment: A reminder that SO rules require askers to describe efforts they have made to solve the problem only when it is a homework question, and "efforts made" does not necessarily mean providing code. Low-rep askers are in any event encouraged to describe efforts they made to solve the problem. Even if it's not a homework problem (e.g., they may be learning Ruby on their own), doing so will head-off requests to do so.

Comment: "i tried some codes, but didn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You didn't write any code, so I won't either.

The documentation of [`Enumerable#chunk_while`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) has an example which is very similar to yours.

Comment: This answer is lit af +1. It will work with `map { |x| (x[0]..x[-1]) }` further.

Comment: Yes it is! Thanks a lot!

Comment: "...so I won't either", but you *will* give a link to code that is ever-ever-ever-so-close to the answer. That's a mighty fine distinction! :-)

Comment: @ray I've got many ruby badges but this is my first "lit af" answer. I'm honored!

Answer (score 0):

This is a way of doing that without constructing an array of arrays and then converting the inner arrays to ranges.

```
arr = [1,2,3,7,9,10,11,13]

arr.each_with_object([]) do |n,a|
  if a.any? and a.last.last == n-1
    a[-1] = (a.last.first..n)
  else
    a << (n..n)
  end
end
  #=> [1..3, 7..7, 9..11, 13..13]
```

Note that parentheses are required around the ranges, lest, for example, `a << n..n` be parsed as `(a << n)..n`, resulting in `ArgumentError (bad value for range)`.